# php oop call variable from class

Tags: php, oop, class, getter-setter

how can i call a variable that's inside a class to another file 
example:

**Controller.php**

```
<?php 
    class hello {
        public $var = 1;

        public function a(){
            ......
        }

        public function b(){
            .....
        }
    }
?>
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php
    $hello = new hello;
    //how to call the $var ? HERE
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Just like this:

```
$hello->var = 2
```

Or to retrive the value:

```
$val = $hello->var;
```

Answer (score 3):

If `var` is public you can do this:

```
$hello->var = $value;
$value = $hello->var;
```

Usually, you do not want to access class members directly.  You could make getters and setters:

```
class hello{
    private $var;

    ...

    function getVar(){
        return $var;
    }

    function setVar($value){
        $var = $value;
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
$hello->getVar();
$hello->setVar($newVarValue);
```

PHP also has magic functions [__get() and __set()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) which allow for access to inaccessible members.  This is basically the same as a getter and setter, but you can get away with one function instead of multiple functions for each member (it can get messy though if not maintainted properly).

So in your class you can do this:

```
class hello{
    private $var;

    ...

    function __get($name){
        if($name == 'var')
            return $var;
    }

    function __set($name, $value){
        if($name == 'var')
            $var = $value;
    }
}
```

but you can still access the members like this:

```
$hello->var = $value;
$value = $hello->var;
```

even though `$var` is private.